# How to print with SmartWebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm using **SmartWebView** to build my HTML app ([SmartWebView](https://github.com/mgks/Android-SmartWebView))

With javascript - **window.print()**, it works on chrome mobile, but nothing happen with SmartWebView. 
I can't find some permissions or options on *MainActivity.java* & *SmartWebView.java* for this print functionality.
Is there any solution for this? Pls help

I'm not familiar with Java and Android Studio. I just can open files and find and change the variables, so I'm worried if I change parts of syntaxes on the functions.

Answer (score 0):

private void doWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {

```
    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

    PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter =
            webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter("MyDocument");

    String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) +
            " Print Test...";

    printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
            new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
}
```

Comment: I wonder.. how can it worked,, since I'm not familiar with Java, but it works with copy/paste :D
Thank you